# How to copy data from sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection?

Tags: java

I am making a debug version of my updater library. Normally, the updater connects to URLs of files to download. The old code looked like this:

```
HttpURLConnection httpConnection;
URL downloadLink = "...";
System.out.println("Downloading update: "+downloadLink);
try {
  httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (downloadLink.openConnection());
}
catch(IOException e) {
  updater.dispatchEvent("download.stopped",ex);
  return;
}
```

The problem is that if the link is link to a file (`file:/C:/.../file.zip`) the `downloadLink.openConnection()` returns `FileURLConnection` instead of `HttpURLConnection`. So I modified the code to be more flexible:

```
URLConnection connection = null;
try {
  connection = downloadLink.openConnection();
} catch (IOException ex) {
  updater.dispatchEvent("download.stopped",ex);
}
System.out.println("Downloading update: "+downloadLink);
if(connection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
  // HTTp downloading code exported to different method
  if(!download_http((HttpURLConnection) connection, updater))
    return false;
}
else if(connection instanceof FileURLConnection) {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Now what?");
}
else {
  updater.dispatchEvent("download.stopped",
      new IllegalStateException("Unknown class type for download conenction: "
          + connection.getClass().getName()));
  return false;
}
```

But I don't know how to use the `FileURLConnection`. And if I google it, I don't even seem to get any relevant results - looks like people don't use it.

The question is: How can I copy data provided by `FileURLConnection` to a new file?

Comment: The same way you read any `URLConnection`. Consume the `InputStream` returned by `URLConnection#getInputStream()` and do whatever you need with it.

Comment: Also, `FileURLConnection` is an implementation provided by your current JRE. Another JRE might use a different implementation of `URLConnection`. Don't rely on `FileURLConnection`, rely on the contract provided by `URLConnection`, which is part of the JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't care which it is. All you need is the input stream, and `URLConnection` provides that. Then you just copy the bytes.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Turns out I could drop the whole if statement.